# wget return downloaded filename

Tags: php, return, wget, filenames

I'm using wget in a php script and need to get the name of the file downloaded.

For example, if I try

```
<?php
  system('/usr/bin/wget -q --directory-prefix="./downloads/" http://www.google.com/');
?>
```

I will get a file called index.html in the downloads directory.

EDIT: The page will not always be google though, the target may be an image or stylesheet, so I need to find out the name of the file that was downloaded.

I'd like to have something like this:

```
<?php
  //Does not work:
  $filename = system('/usr/bin/wget -q --directory-prefix="./downloads/" http://www.google.com/');
  //$filename should contain "index.html"
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using php to find the most recently updated file in the directory using the following code:

```
<?php
system('/usr/bin/wget -q --directory-prefix="./downloads/" http://www.google.com/');
$dir = "./downloads";

$newstamp = 0;
$newname = "";
$dc = opendir($dir);
while ($fn = readdir($dc)) {
  # Eliminate current directory, parent directory
  if (ereg('^\.{1,2}$',$fn)) continue;
  $timedat = filemtime("$dir/$fn");
  if ($timedat > $newstamp) {
    $newstamp = $timedat;
    $newname = $fn;
  }
}
// $newname contains the name of the most recently updated file
// $newstamp contains the time of the update to $newname
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe that's some kind of *cheating*, but why not :

- decide yourself the name of the file that `wget` should create
- indicate to `wget` that the download should be made to that file
- when the download is finished, use that file -- as you already know the name.

Check out the `-O` option of wget ;-)

For example, running this from the command-line :

```
wget 'http://www.google.com/' -O my-output-file.html
```

Will create a file called `my-output-file.html`.

Comment: +1 - Solving problems often entails asking yourself if you are solving the right problem :)

Comment: Good solution, but I should have clarified that the target of wget may be an image or stylesheet, or any other file. I updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

if your requirement is simple like just getting `google.com`, then do it within PHP

```
$data=file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/');
file_put_contents($data,"./downloads/output.html");
```

Comment: Seems the best answer to me - i.e. call the file what you want, rather than having to get the file name, and avoid executing shell scripts from PHP. To find out whether the file is css, html, etc get the Content-Type string automatically populated in the $http_reponse_header array.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux like systems you can do:

```
system('/usr/bin/wget -q --directory-prefix="./downloads/" http://www.google.com/');
$filename = system('ls -tr ./downloads'); // $filename is now index.html
```

This works if there is no other process creating file in the `./downloads` directory.

Comment: do you really need to call system `ls` to do directory listing in PHP ? :) How about PHP's own `readdir()` or `glob()`

Comment: I ended up doing something similar, but avoided the system call. To get the most recently updated file, I used this code:
`code`
$dir = "./downloads";

$newstamp = 0;
$newname = "";
$dc = opendir($dir);
while ($fn = readdir($dc)) {
  # Eliminate current directory, parent directory
  if (ereg('^\.{1,2}$',$fn)) continue;
  $timedat = filemtime("$dir/$fn");
  if ($timedat > $newstamp) {
    $newstamp = $timedat;
    $newname = $fn;
  }
}

Comment: Code came out messed up, should have been an answer anyway, so I added it as an answer too.